# Code leaking, latter #If statement not closing former #If

Tags: autohotkey

### The problem

Upon pressing the left mouse button, the hotkey for `Win`+`Z` gets triggered with it (or basically *any* code below the `LButton` hotkey)

---

### What is it?

It's an AutoHotkey toggle for a Rainmeter HUD.

---

### The code

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class RainmeterMeterWindow")
~LButton::
{
Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !Hide *
WinMinimizeAllUndo
rainystate := 0
}
#If


#z::
{
if (rainystate = 0)
{
    WinMinimizeAll
    Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !RainmeterZPos 1 *
    Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !Show *
    Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !RainmeterZPos 0 "WP7\Background"
    Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !RainmeterZPos 2 "WP7\Panels\Computer"
    rainystate := 1
}
else
{
    Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !Hide *
    WinMinimizeAllUndo
    rainystate := 0
}
Sleep 50
Return
}
```

---

### Stuff I tried

- **Moved the whole #If block in a different position**

  - It ran its code, then triggered the hotkey below it
- **Tried** `#IfWinActive ahk_class RainmeterMeterWindow` **instead**

  - Problem persists

---

### What *might* be causing the problem

The `#If` statement right below the closing curly brace `}` (the one at line 8)

---

---

I think it's supposed to work because the AHK docs (http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_If.htm) states the following:

> To turn off context sensitivity, specify #If or any #IfWin directive but omit all the parameters. For example:
>
> `#If`

which was exactly what was done.

I just have no idea what exactly is the problem, other than the `#If WinActive("ahk_class RainmeterMeterWindow")` leaking to the code below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `Return` after your first hotkey. A hotkey's code runs until it hits a `Return`.  Your script should look like this. I've also done some formatting for you.

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class RainmeterMeterWindow")
    ~LButton::
        Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !Hide *
        WinMinimizeAllUndo
        rainystate := 0
    Return   ; This was missing
#If


#z::
    if (rainystate = 0)
    {
        WinMinimizeAll
        Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !RainmeterZPos 1 *
        Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !Show *
        Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !RainmeterZPos 0 "WP7\Background"
        Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !RainmeterZPos 2 "WP7\Panels\Computer"
        rainystate := 1
    }
    else
    {
        Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !Hide *
        WinMinimizeAllUndo
        rainystate := 0
    }
    Sleep 50
Return
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! Pretty careless for me there. Turns out the solution was just a *single* line of code.

Comment: @SimonClemente Welcome to coding!